# How to check if URL has a numbers or String at the end by Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urlparse

I have 2 types of URLS

the first one has numbers at the end of url

```
www.example.fr/drive/cat.productlist.pagination_0.topage/2?t:ac=3686962/3686315
```

the second one:

```
www.example.com/some/cat.productlist.pagination_0.topage/4?t:ac=someText
```

how can i know my input is like first one or second one?

i tried this:

```
myURL = http://www.example.com/some/cat.productlist.pagination_0.topage/4?t:ac=someText
                        parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(myURL)
                        number2, number3 = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)["t:ac"][0].split("/")

                        if ( isinstance( number2, numbers.Number) and isinstance( number3, numbers.Number) ) :
                            print "first"
                        else :
                            print "second"
```

Comment: Why have you mentioned regex here?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried by urlParse, but i want to do that by regex

Comment: @parik, did you know regex stands for regular expression?
Whats the meaning of your title?

Comment: @MohitC I would like to know how can i solve my problem with regex, excuse-me if my title is not clear, i read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and i don't undrestand why my title is not good, i edit my title

Comment: Why did you @ me? I didn't criticise your title.

Comment: Your title earlier was 'regular expressions in python regex' and my comment was for that

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, sorry man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to check if the url ends with numbers or letters i.e.:

```
if re.search(r"\d+$", url):
    # url ends with numbers
if re.search("[a-z]+$", url, re.IGNORECASE):
    # url ends with letters
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to do this with regex, but this would work:

```
if re.search(r't:ac=(\d+)', myURL):
    print "numbers"
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is more or less correct already, but usually in python you just convert the data into the data format you wish, until it breaks (ask forgiveness not permission principle)

So you can try something like this (in Python3),

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

myURL = 'http://www.example.com/some/cat.productlist.pagination_0.topage/4?t:ac=someText'

query = parse_qs(urlparse(myURL).query)

try:
    number2, number3 = query.get('t:ac', [''])[0].split('/')

    # do something with the numbers
    new_number = int(number2) + int(number3)

    print('first')
except ValueError:
    # t:ac does not have a slash in it
    print('second')
```

(Python2)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

myURL = 'http://www.example.com/some/cat.productlist.pagination_0.topage/4?t:ac=someText'

query = parse_qs(urlparse(myURL).query)

try:
    number2, number3 = query.get('t:ac', [''])[0].split('/')

    # do something with the numbers
    new_number = int(number2) + int(number3)

    print('first')
except ValueError:
    # t:ac does not have a slash in it
    print('second')
```

it is not that asking permission is not possible, just that it probably wouldn't look as elegant

```
if number2.isdigit() and number3.isdigit():
    print("first")
else :
    print("second")
```

Comment: also if you are not writing code for existing python2 application, or requiring the use of old libraries, please write only in python 3 (:

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i work with Scrapy and i have to write in python 2.7